# Tooling API giving error of resource not found

Tags: apex, rest-api, tooling-api

I am trying to do a simple code with Tooling API, where I am trying to execute anonymous one statement with tooling API.

Sample request -

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + SESSION_ID);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            String code = 'System.debug(\'Test\')';
            String contentValue = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(code, 'UTF-8');
            req.setEndpoint('https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v28.0/tooling/executeAnonymous/anonymousBody=' + contentValue + '/');
            req.setMethod('GET');
```

The error that I am getting is

```
[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]
```

Any idea why I am getting this. The /sobjects tooling request work wothout issue while /sobjects/contact/describe gives same error as above.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: why negative on question? Please add comments

Answer (score -2, accepted):

So this got solved. There was a missing ? symbol after "tooling/".That is why the error was coming.

Comment: Why it does not answer my own question? Still added an edit

Comment: can you please ellaborate more here with actual working code written again in answer .